# How can we share a pricebook record to a group using apex code

Tags: pricebook, apex-sharing, sharerecord

I want to share record of `Pricebook` to a group. Their is no object called `PricebookShare`, how can we share if there is no object `PricebookShare` to share? Is there any way? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Currently one has to manually share PriceBook record. Although the Pricebookshare object exists, but it is not accessible.

Comment: is there any way we can access Pricebookshare object

Comment: currently it is not possible. you could create an idea for exposing pricebookshare object.